# React test not working using Vite + Vitest

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, vite, vitest

I am getting the following error when running `npm test` (which calls `vitest`):

> FAIL  src/Applications/components/ApplicationsTable/ApplicationsTable.test.tsx [ src/Applications/components/ApplicationsTable/ApplicationsTable.test.tsx ]
> Error: Directory import '{internalNpmPackage}/build/components' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from {internalNpmPackage}/build/index.js
> ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
> Serialized Error: { code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT', url: 'file:///Users/me/{myProject}/node_modules/{internalNpmProject}/build/components' }

Where 'internalNpmPackage' is an internal npm package (shared react components lib) and 'myProject' is the react project I'm testing.

The project runs fine with vite, it's just testing I get this issue.

The 'internalNpmPackage' is a collection of react components that are exported, and are importing fine when serving the project.

I am using React, TS, Vite and Vitest.

When I link these packages locally (using Yalc, similar to npm link - it works fine)

Comment: Are you passing any flags when you're running the project?

Comment: I run the test with "vite --open"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was to add to vite config under 'test':

```
server: {
    deps: {
      inline: ['{internalNpmPackage}'],
    },
  },
```

According to vite docs:

*Vite will process inlined modules. This could be helpful to handle packages that ship .js in ESM format (that Node can't handle).*

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the directory index if not done already. If your current import statement is
`import { component1, component2} from '{internalNpmPackage}/build/components'`,

try changing it to

`import { component1, component2} from '{internalNpmPackage}/build/components/index.js'`

Refer - https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions

If the above solution doesn't work for you, please share your import statement that is causing the error, the package.json of the internal package and also the folder structure of your project

Comment: Problem import is:
`import { PageHeader } from '{internalNpmPackage}';`
Changing to:
`import { PageHeader } from '{internalNpmPackage}/build/components/index.js';`
Still has issues.

I resolved this and will add an answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider Using ts-jest for TypeScript
If you are not already using ts-jest for TypeScript projects, consider switching to it for better compatibility with TypeScript in Jest.

```
npm install --save-dev ts-jest
```

you can check detail in documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started